# To convert a cv::Mat to CvArr*

Tags: opencv

I am using the transpose function cvTranspose to transpose a matrix. The code goes below:

```
CvMat matrix1, matrixTr;
double a[] = { 1,  2,  3,  4,
               5,  6,  7,  8,
               9, 10, 11, 12 };

CvMat matrix1=cvMat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, a);
cvTranspose(matrix1,matrixTr);
```

This is where the error comes:cannot convert `'CvMat {aka CvMat}'` to `'constCvArr* {aka const void*}'` for argument `'1'` to `'void cvTranspose(const CvArr*, CvArr)'`

I quite new to programming ...plz do let me know ur thoughts and suggestions...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvTranspose takes 2 pointers to CvArr, CvMat is derived from CvArr, so you should do  the following :

```
cvTranspose(&matrix1, &matrixTr);
```